# 403 Forbidden - Angular 7 Application

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My website is returning `403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server` when entering domain.com or https://example.com

But works well in https://www.example.com

It works well in domain.com/file but gives the error in https://example.com/file

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Is there anything missing within my .htaccess? Or is it caused because of other things?

Comment: this is related to domain configuration not angular?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.htacces` specified in the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples), it worked perfectly for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```